# performSegueWithIdentifier: causes app to crash

Tags: ios, objective-c, segue

I have a button that is pressed after user enters email information. I have an alert view that is displayed when there is no email entered but if there is I want the button to segue to another view controller.

The following code causes my app to crash. I have no idea why. Please help.

(note: I have tried "sender:self]" "sender:nil]" and "sender:sender]" and they all make my app crash.)

```
- (IBAction)nextButtonPushed:(id)sender {

    if ([self.emailTextField.text  isEqual: @""]) {

        emailAlertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Missing Email" message:@"A destination email is required to send." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [emailAlertView show];
        self.nextButton.enabled = NO;
    }

    else {

        eString = self.eTextField.text;
        hString = self.hField.text;
        emailAddress = self.emailTextField.text;

        [userDefaults setObject:eString forKey:@"e"];

        [userDefaults setObject:hString forKey:@"h"];

        [userDefaults setObject:emailAddress forKey:@"email"];

        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"next" sender:self];
    }

}
```

Comment: Could you show the error message.

Comment: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Receiver (<FirstViewController: 0xc1ad2f0>) has no segue with identifier 'next''
*** First throw call stack:
(blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Comment: Did you create the segue in the StoryBoard and name it "next"?

Comment: It says Receiver has no segue with identifier, but I can promise you I put one in there. I control clicked from view controller 1 to view controller two and made a modal segue (flip horizontal) named "next".

Comment: `has no segue with identifier 'next''` .... its telling you the issue

Comment: take a screenshot of the segue showing what its connected to and the Id

Comment: "I can promise you I put one in there" I can promise you that you didn't. The compiler/runtime knows much more than you do.

Comment: I just took a picture to prove to you, but I don't have a 10 on this website so i couldn't show it to you. But yes, it IS there.

Comment: @digimortal host it on imgur.com and post the link

Comment: if the segue is connected, check that the origin view controller has the correct class in storyboard (FirstViewController and not UIViewController). Moreover, try a clean - clean build folder on the project.

Comment: https://www.flickr.com/photos/foreverframes/13431061083/

Comment: This is the link to the image of my segue     flickr.com/photos/foreverframes/13431061083

Comment: Look at the image. There is another view controller scene hidden under the one on the left. You've connected the segue from the wrong view controller.

Comment: Choose Editor > Show Document Outline and use the outline to see where the segue really is.

Comment: matt you have humbled this noob. that was the problem.

Answer (score 5):

There are three overwhelmingly likely possibilities:

- Perhaps the storyboard really has no segue named "next" emerging from the FirstViewController scene. Be careful: spaces and capitalization and things like that matter.
- Perhaps the storyboard has a segue named "next" but it emerges from a different scene (a different view controller).
- Perhaps the FirstViewController instance represented by `self` in your code is not the same as the FirstViewController instance in the storyboard, i.e. maybe it came into existence in some other way and not by instantiation from the storyboard. You might even have two FirstViewController objects in the storyboard, and the segue comes from the other one.

Comment: Your last comment is interesting. I have this kind of rare random crashes, which might be explained by having multiple copies of same storyboard object. Thanx, +1.

Answer (score 4):

One great way to figure out why your app is crashing on a line like this is to disable any breakpoints you may have (including exception breakpoints). This will cause the app to crash and often tell you a reason why it is crashing. Normally you'll get error's like @matt mentioned such as bad identifiers on your seques (often typing errors), multiple of the same object in an IB scene such as the following:

```
 Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Receiver (<YOURAPP.YOURVIEWCONTROLLER: 0x7c8951d0>) has no segue with identifier 'TheSequeIdentifierYouHaventSetYetOrTypedInWrong''
```

or like in my case today where I got this error:

```
 Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<YOURAPP.YOURVIEWCONTROLLERYOUARETRYINGTOSHOW 0x78e5a140> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key "MyKeyOnTheOffendingObject"
```

Once I knew that I had an object in my storyboard with a key that it should not have all I had to do was track down the Button/Image/Other Random Object with the bad *Referencing Outlet* or *Sent Event* and all was fixed

Often `performSequeWithIdentifier` will come up as the last line shown before a crash since that is the last line that worked before a problem was found when presenting a new View Controller - so if you are sure the problem isn't with your seque then check references on the VC you are trying to present!

Comment: This helped me debug my issue as I was stuck thinking it was the segue but turned out to be something in Storyboard!

Answer (score 3):

Crashing can also occur if the view controller cannot load from the NIB. For example if there is an incorrectly named User Defined Runtime Attribute.

For example `QBFlatButton` changed their API today and my app started crashing. This is why we use semantic versioning :-)

Comment: Exactly "User Defined Runtime Attribute" can be a huge problem in relatin to this.  You can get really weird effects where the ONLY WAY to fix the crash is to rewind to an earlier version of the storyboard.  Merely removing the User Defined Runtime Attribute often still results in this weird crash.  I'd say it's a plain bug in Xcode.